# JavaFX filter implementation (How to handle multiple Boolean options)

Tags: java, javafx, filter, tablefilter

I'm working with JavaFX and I want to implement a filter to acces datas from a database. Depending on what checkboxes are selected, I want to execute a specific sql statement to retrieve data from my database. The problem is that if I add multiple filters I don't know how to manage them. I don't want to write a different select for each combination, beacuse there are too many.
[image]

I feel like is a logical problem. Is there a way to store those check-boxes somehow and then easily check whether they are selected or not and based on that, I want to be able to construct the sql statement to retrive the data I want.

I just need an ideea to start from, not a code example, maybe from someone who implemented this on a website.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it : use binary, treat each option a bit and get unique statuses. A very simple example (note that this example is not a good implementation. It is just a demonstration of a possible approach):

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        //each booleans represents an option (the state of one check box )
        //this example simulates 3 options 
        boolean option1 = true;
        boolean option2 = true;
        boolean option3 = true;

        //represent each boolean as binary (0 or 1 ) string
        String binString1 = (option1) ? "1" : "0";
        String binString2 = (option2) ? "1" : "0";
        String binString3 = (option3) ? "1" : "0";

        //add all strings to one word 
        String binaryAsString = binString1+binString2+binString3;

        //phrase it to int 
        // Use as radix 2 because it's binary
        int number = Integer.parseInt(binaryAsString, 2);

        //for 3 options (bits) you will get 8 different values, from 
        //0 (all false) to 7 (all true)
        System.out.println(option1 + " "+ option2 + " "+ option3 + " = "+ number);

    }
```

Ouput examples: 

false false false = 0

false true false = 2

true true true = 7

A possible implementation of the the idea demonstrated above:

```
     /**
     *<pre>
     * Converts an array of booleans, in the ordered entered, to a binary word,
     * where each boolean represents one bit. The binary word is returned as int.
     * <br>usage example:
     * <br>   boolToInt(false,true,false) returns 2(binary 010).
     * <br>   boolToInt(true,true,false)  returns 6(binary 110).
     *
     *@param bols
     *@throws IllegalArgumentException if bols is null or empty.
     *@return
     *<pre>
     */
    private static int boolToInt(boolean ... bols) {

        if((bols == null) || (bols.length == 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid (null or empty )input" );
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for( boolean b : bols) {
            sb.append( (b) ?   "1" : "0"  );
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the `CheckBox`es in a array and `Function<Boolean, String>` in another array/`List`, use streams to map from `CheckBox` state to condition and use `Collectors.joining` to generate a query.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[]{new CheckBox("a"), new CheckBox("b"), new CheckBox("c")};
    List<Function<Boolean, String>> clausesConstructor = Arrays.asList(
            b -> b ? "a >= 1" : null,
            b -> b ? "b LIKE '%42'" : null,
            b -> b ? "c" : null
    );

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Query");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, boxes.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> clausesConstructor.get(i).apply(boxes[i].isSelected()))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(list.isEmpty() ? "SELECT * FROM table" : list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(") AND (", "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (", ")")));
    });
    VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(boxes);
    vbox.getChildren().add(btn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```